# How can I get my rule to fire?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm working on list fusion rules for `fromListN` in [`Data.Primitive.Array`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.6.3.0/docs/Data-Primitive-Array.html), and I'm a bit stuck. The function looks like this:

```
fromListNArray :: Int -> [a] -> Array a
fromListNArray !n l =
  createArray n fromListN_too_short $ \mi ->
    let go i (x:xs)
          | i < n = writeArray mi i x >> go (i+1) xs
          | otherwise = fromListN_too_long
        go i [] = unless (i == n) fromListN_too_short
     in go 0 l
{-# NOINLINE fromListNArray #-}
```

`fromListN_too_short` and `fromListN_too_long` are just error calls.

My rewrite rules are

```
{-# RULES
"fromListNArray/foldr" [~1] forall n xs.
  fromListNArray n xs = createArray n fromListN_too_short $ \mary ->
    foldr (fillArray_go n mary) (fillArray_stop n) xs 0

"fillArrayN/list" [1] forall n mary xs i.
  foldr (fillArray_go n mary) (fillArray_stop n) xs i = fillArrayN n mary xs i
 #-}
```

where the helpers are defined

```
fillArrayN :: Int -> MutableArray s a -> [a] -> Int -> ST s ()
fillArrayN !n !mary xs0 !i0 = go i0 xs0
  where
    go i (x:xs)
      | i < n = writeArray mary i x >> go (i+1) xs
      | otherwise = fromListN_too_long
    go i [] = unless (i == n) fromListN_too_short
{-# NOINLINE fillArrayN #-}

fillArray_go :: Int
             -> MutableArray s a
             -> a
             -> (Int -> ST s ())
             -> Int
             -> ST s ()
fillArray_go !n !mary = \x r i ->
  if i < n
    then writeArray mary i x >> r (i + 1)
    else fromListN_too_long
{-# INLINE CONLIKE [0] fillArray_go #-}

fillArray_stop :: Int -> Int -> ST s ()
fillArray_stop !n = \i -> unless (i == n) fromListN_too_short
{-# INLINE [0] fillArray_stop #-}
```

The first rewrite rule seems to do okay. The second, write-back, rule is the problem. I can never seem to get it to fire. Can anyone offer a suggestion?

---

Note: I know I could just fuse directly with `build` and `augment` to avoid having to write back, but it's ... not a pretty sight.

Comment: I'm sure I haven't understood what you're trying to do, but `fromListNArray/foldr` seems like a strange rewrite rule to me. Rewrite rules are for spotting particular usage patterns but `fromListNArray/foldr` just looks for any (saturated) use of `fromListNArray`. Why not just define `fromListNArray n xs = createArray n fromListN_too_short $ \mary ->  fillArrayN n mary xs 0`?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, compare what I'm doing to the rules in `GHC.Base` and `GHC.List`.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it - the first rule tries to make it fuse-able and the second rule undoes the first if fusion didn't happen. Is that right?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, yes, that's the goal.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something even though I was wholly unhelpful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem appears to be a mistake on my part. In

```
"fillArrayN/list" [1] forall n mary xs i.
  foldr (fillArray_go n mary) (fillArray_stop n) xs i = fillArrayN n mary xs i
```

the `foldr` is `Data.Foldable.foldr`, which is a class method and therefore doesn't work on the LHS of a rule. Fixing this problem makes the write-back rule work in simple cases.

Unfortunately, when `fromListNArray` fuses with `augment` (which typically happens when it's applied to appended lists), the rule fails to fire for another reason. GHC creates a function for `fillArray_go n mary`, and doesn't inline it. I still don't understand why this happens.